# How can I extract a number from a command's output?

Tags: text-processing

How may I structure a command to print only `2.60` from the following string (the output from another command, `lscpu`):

```
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz
```

Comment: That would be very easy using "sed", but I'll take bets you actually want to ask the kernel for the maximum clock frequency? Because that can be directly queried from a virtual file.

Comment: What language? (bash?)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean to print the number between `@<whitespaces>` and `GHz` at the end of lines that start with `model name`, that would be:

```
sed -nE 's/^model name.*@[[:space:]]*([.[:digit:]]+)GHz$/\1/p' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Or with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^model name.*@\s*\K[.\d]+(?=GHz$)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

With `lscpu`, see also:

```
lscpu -J | jq -r '
  .lscpu[] |
  select(.field == "Model name:").data |
  match("@\\s*([\\d.]+)GHz$").captures[0].string |
  tonumber'
```

Or:

```
lscpu -J | jq -r '.lscpu[]|select(.field == "CPU max MHz:").data|tonumber'
```

For the max frequency in MHz instead of the base frequency from the model name.

Comment: How will structure the command from the command lscpu?

Comment: @guy see edit. You could also pipe the output of `lspcu` to those `grep`/`sed` commands, but on my system at least, there's no line starting with `model name` (`Model name` instead), so you'd need to adapt it. See also the `-i` option of `grep`  (or the `i`/`I` modifiers for `s` command of GNU `sed`) for case-insensitive matching

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` (GNU `sed` for its `I` flag for case insensitive matching).

```
$ lscpu | sed -En 's/^model name.* ([0-9.]+).*/\1/Ip'
2.60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `awk`:

```
awk '{print int($NF*100)/100.0}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

this line can be rewrited but I am not sure how different `awk` implementations will handle it:

```
awk '{print $NF*1.0}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

This will print `2.6`. If you want to have it with zero you can use:

```
awk '{printf "%4.2f",int($NF*100)/100.0}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you want to use `lscpu` you can it on this way:

```
lscpu|awk '/odel name/ {print int($NF*100)/100.0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<command>| awk '{gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,"",$NF);print $NF}'
```

```
Tested with echoing the following command output
echo "model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz"| awk '{print $NF}'|sed "s/[a-zA-Z]//g"
```

```
output

2.60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LANG=C lscpu | sed -rn "s/.*Model name.* @ (.*)GHz/\1/p"
```

The `LANG=C` is needed, if your language setting isn't set to English.

The -n for sed suppresses output by default. The -r is for simpliefied typing of capturing groups (without backslash).

The "s/A/B/p" command substitutes A with B and the p performs a print, if condition A is met (since we suppressed output by default, that's neccessary).

A is the regex, and `\1` the first (and only) capture group.